# How to get all dictionaries in a list that match a given criteron

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dictionary entries:

```
list = ( 
          {"hammer" : "woodwork", "name" : "Mjolnir", "country": "NO"}, 
          {"chisel" : "woodwork", "name" : "Cold Chisel", "country": "AU"},
          {"chisel" : "masonry", "name" : "Bolster", "country": "AU"},
          {"drill" : "masonry/woodwork", "name" : "All purpose Drill", "country": "NO"}
        )
```

Can someone guide me as to the most Pythonic way to retrieve all dictionaries from the list where the value for the key `country` contains "NO"?

Bonus points for how to repeat the iteration so that if I then want to select from that subset anything which has a value from the other seemingly random keys of `woodwork`

Thanks in advance for any/all assistance received.

**Note**
As yet, I've failed to fully grasp how a list of dictionaries can be handled other than by iterating over them one by one. This strikes me as achievable but probably (definitely) massively inefficient, hence my request for a more Pythonic way to deal with this.

Comment: `[d for d in list if "NO" in d["country"]]`?

Comment: Also, you should avoid using built-in names like `list` as variable names. Especially since your `list` is not a list – it's a tuple.